# Assertion failure in UICollectionView with supplementary views / section headers, dataSource is nil?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Every once in a while on of my Apps reports this assertion failure via Crashlytics:

```
 Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException 
 UICollectionView dataSource is not set

0   CoreFoundation  __exceptionPreprocess + 126
3   Foundation  -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 92
4   UIKit   -[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 148
5   UIKit   -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 3398
6   UIKit   -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 240
7   UIKit   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 514
8   QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 136
9   QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 360
10  QuartzCore  CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 16
11  QuartzCore  CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 222
12  QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::commit() + 324
13  UIKit   _afterCACommitHandler + 132
14  CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
20  UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1440
21  NRDB    main.m line 14 main
22  libdyld.dylib   start + 2
```

In all three places where the app uses UICollectionViews, I've made sure that a) the dataSource is set both in the XIB and in the controller's `viewDidLoad` method, and b) that it's reset to nil in the controller's `dealloc`.

The supplementary views (a header view) is added to the collection views using

```
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"HeaderXib" bundle:nil] forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"sectionHeader"];
```

For the header views, I'm using [CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout).

So far, I have been unable to reproduce this locally. Any ideas as to what could be the problem, or even how to figure out which of the three views is involved?

Comment: "I have been unable to reproduce this locally." Can you tell us what you've been doing to test it? Do you have access to to same type of device the app is crashing on?

Comment: This basically means that I've never seen the crash in the simulator or ony any of my two iPads (Air and mini, this is an iPad only app). Also, this hasn't happened to any of my Testflight testers so far.

Comment: re: what I've been doing to test: since I have no idea which of the three uses of UICollectionView is involved, I've simply tried all sorts of "unusual" behaviour in all three places, to no avail. I'm pretty sure this does not occur during "normal" use, the app as a few thousand users, compared to 58 reports in Crashlytics, so I'm guessing it must be some rare egde case, and my first priority would be to figure out which view is the culprit.

Comment: And there's no way to make Crashlytics tell you which view it's trying to load before it loads it? No consistency in which version of iOS the error happens in? (It's a shame there's no way to contact the people who *are* getting the error.)

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The next version of the app will have an "oops" alert on startup following a crash, asking people to tell me what they just did.

Comment: That's probably the best option. I'm sorry I couldn't actually help. I'm baffled that your testers have never had this happen either.

Comment: are you sure ***dataSource is set***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Minimize your guesswork:**

Subclass your collection views wherever you use them, scoped to that location:

```
@interface MyDetailViewController_CollectionView : UICollectionView

@end

@implentation MyDetailViewController_CollectionView

-(void)layoutSubviews{
    //When the stacktrace is generated, it will now include -[MyDetailViewController_CollectionView layoutSubviews]
    [super layoutSubviews];
}

@end
```

Then set those controllers to have instances of their corresponding collection views. This can be done in interface builder by setting a custom class.

If you implement this, manually trigger an exception to make sure that the stack trace looks the way you want it to. You should be able to do it in -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

**UICollectionView.dataSource is weak**

It would seem that the  likely scenario is that the controller is being destroyed, but the collection view survives somehow.

When you dealloc a controller, make sure that all strong references to the collection view and any containing views are set to nil.

**UIViews can survive in the view hierarchy**

On dealloc add an assert NSAssert(self.collectionView.window == nil). If the window is not nil then the collection view is part of the view hierarchy and can receive layout events even though the controller has been destroyed.

This can be caused by

- manually adding/removing view controller views to the view hierarchy
- deallocating a view controller before its dismissal animation is complete

Comment: Thanks for the subclassing suggestion, I'm going to add that immediately.

Comment: Re: dataSource being weak, I'm aware of that, and my dealloc does `self.collectionView.delegate = nil; self.collectionView.dataSource = nil; self.collectionView = nil;`

Comment: I've been in situations where my view controller was dealloc'd but the view was still in the hierarchy, due to an animation or some other mechanism that went beyond simple navigation controllers.

Comment: How do you detect/avoid such cases? `self.collectionView=nil` in `viewWillDisappear` maybe?

Comment: On dealloc add an assert `NSAssert(self.collectionView.window == nil)`. If the window is not nil then the collection view can get receive layout events after the controller has been destroyed. I wouldn't recommend anything like adding `[self.collectionView removeFromSuperview]` to dealloc because you shouldn't have to do that. The problem is possibly in a custom transition outside of the class or something like that.

Comment: As was to be expected, those asserts don't trigger during normal usage. I don't have any custom transitions or animations really, these are simple non-animated dismissals of popovers (1 case) or replacements of the detail view in a UISplitViewController (2 cases).

Still, your suggestions are very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any blocks referencing the collection view or its parents? for instance a `[_collectionView setNeedsLayout]` in a network callback?